# Achar atalho do Atom

Tags: css, atom

Hoje, enquanto eu estava trabalhando em um CSS com o Atom, eu abri uma sugestão de emotes para usar através de um atalho acidentalmente, porém eu não sei qual atalho eu usei e gostaria de saber. Alguém sabe?

Eu não utilizo nenhum package de emotes.

Comment: Caso utilize *Windows 10*, basta utilizar as teclas `Windows` + `.` (Ponto)

Comment: BOA! É isso mesmo que eu abri, muito obrigado.

Comment: Se o seu sistema operacional for Windows 10+ e o seu teclado for PT-BR aperte `⊞ Win + ç` que vai abrir a janela de emojis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver a lista de emotes é só utilizar <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.